# Wicket FileUploadField and large zip uploads

Tags: java, zip, wicket

I'm using wicket to have large (~2Gb+) zip files submitted to a web application, to process the zip file I'm using the java.util.zip.* classes and I need to be able to read random entries from the zip file. So my code is something like this:

```
class MyForm extends Form {
    private FileUploadField fileField;

    MyForm(String id) {
        super(id);
        fileField = new FileUploadField("upload");
        add(fileField);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {
        FileUpload fileUpload = fileField.getFileUpload();
        File file = fileUpload.writeToTempFile();
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
        // Do more stuff
    }
}
```

As the upload is large wicket puts it in a temp file when parsing the request, but then writeToTempFile() copies it into another temp file, so I now have two copies of the file on disk. This wastes disk space, disk IO and increased the request processing time.

I can't use ZipFileInputStream as I need to access the files in a random order. Is there a way to stop wicket duplicating the file on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's not a nice way.

You can subclass `FileUploadField` and override the `getFileUpload()` method with a copy that exposes the underlying `FileItem`.

Or, another way is to create a new method in your `FileUploadField` subclass just to return the `FileItem`:

```
public FileItem getFileItem() {
    return ((IMultipartWebRequest)getRequest()).getFile(getInputName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. To complete this a FileItem still doesn't give you access to the File, DiskFileItem which implements FileItem has the method getStoreLocation() which does, so a test and cast.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer from @biziclop I wrote this class:

```
public class RawFileUploadField extends FileUploadField {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public RawFileUploadField(String id) {
    super(id);
}

/**
 * Attempts to get the file that is on disk if it exists and if it doesn't
 * then just write the file to a temp location.
 * @return The file or <code>null</code> if no file.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public File getFile() throws IOException {
    // Get request
    final Request request = getRequest();

    // If we successfully installed a multipart request
    if (request instanceof IMultipartWebRequest)
    {
        // Get the item for the path
        FileItem item = ((IMultipartWebRequest)request).getFile(getInputName());
        if (item instanceof DiskFileItem) {
            File location = ((DiskFileItem)item).getStoreLocation();
            if (location != null) {
                return location;
            }
        }
    }
    // Fallback
    FileUpload upload = getFileUpload();
    return (upload != null)?upload.writeToTempFile():null;
    }

}
```